# Django conditional require for an entire form

Tags: django, django-forms

How do I conditionally require the filling of an entire form based on a field of another form that is on the same page?

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class OptionForm(forms.Form):
    """Whether or not the user wants to fill the contact form"""
    fill_form = forms.BooleanField(initial=True)

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    phone = forms.CharField(required=False)
    # ... and many more fields
```

Specification:

If the user ticks the checkbox in OptionForm, it means that he/she wants to fill in ContactForm, so we must make sure that ContactForm is filled and is correct/validates. On the other hand, if the user unticks the checkbox, we should ignore all input in ContactForm.

How do I achieve the specification outlined above? I am using function based views. One solution I can think of is to only run `is_valid()` based on the value of the checkbox. The complication with this is that the rendered html ContactForm's inputs have the required attribute, preventing the user from submitting the form if ContactForm is blank even though the user has unchecked the checkbox.

Comment: Go with that solution if you need server side validation.

Answer (score 0):

Django doesn't prevent you from submitting a form if its required fields are blank; it will be your browser doing that. Use `novalidate` in the `<form>` element to disable this.

Comment: Isn't it that in recent versions of django, if the forms.Charfield has argument `required=True` (implicitly or explicitly), there will be a required attribute for the html input tag?

Comment: Yes. But as I said, it is the browser that is using those attributes to prevent you from submitting, and you can disable that.